# NullInjectorError only on route resolver

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have a component declared in a feature module, with routing module

```
import { TestResolverService } from './service/test.resolver.service';
import { MyComponent } from './containers/my-component/mycomponent.component';


const routes: Routes =
  [
    {
        path: '',
        component: MyComponent,
        resolve: TestResolverService
    },
  ];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class MyRoutingModule { }
```

TestResolverService is defined within the same module here:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestResolverService implements Resolve<void>{

  constructor() { }
  resolve(x, y) {}
}
```

The module is lazy loaded from root:

```
{path: 'mymodule', loadChildren: () => import('./features/test/mymodule.module').then(m => m.MyModule)}
```

Whenever I try to load the page with the `resolve` in place I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(PathwaysModule)[TestResolverService_Factory -> TestResolverService_Factory -> TestResolverService_Factory -> TestResolverService_Factory]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for TestResolverService_Factory!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(MyModule)[TestResolverService_Factory -> TestResolverService_Factory -> TestResolverService_Factory -> TestResolverService_Factory]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for TestResolverService_Factory!
```

What am I missing?  The page loads fine without the `resolve`, and importing and calling the service directly from the component works too.  It is only when referenced as a resolver that I am getting this issue.

Comment: The ```TestResolverService``` is imported in the module already.  I'm still receiving the error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing `resolve: TestResolverService` to

```
resolve: { resolver: TestResolverService }
```

I had the resolve type figured wrong.